# Is there a way to test this anonymous function on $rootScope.$on?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

Here's the controller I'm working with:

```
function CategoryController($rootScope, CategoryList, ProductList) {
var vm = this;
vm.categories = CategoryList;
vm.products = ProductList;
$rootScope.$on('OC:FacetsUpdated', function(e, productList) {
    productList ? vm.products = productList : vm.products = ProductList;
})
```

}

I would like to test that when the broadcast is fired the vm.products value will change if productList(from the broadcast) has a value.

I know I can trigger the broadcast, but as far as I know I can't spyOn an anonymous function. Thoughts?

Comment: Why would you have to spy it? emit the event, and check that vm.products is initialized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As said by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) it wouldn't make sense to `spyOn` the function you want to test. Your purpose here is that you want to test the logic of the anonymous function, so just emit the event and check that your `vm.products` have changed.